# I can't execute SQL sentence twice

Tags: php, html, css

I can't execute SQL twice somehow.
In the case of below code, 1st SQL sentence【SELECT h.title, h.place, h.introduction ~】works. And 2nd one【SELECT name ~】 doesn't work.

If I change 1st SQL sentence to comment out, 2nd SQL work correctly.

Do you notice how to work both of SQL.

```
<?php
function dbconnect(){
  $db = new mysqli('localhost:8889', 'root', 'root', 'airbnb');
  // if (! $db){
  //   die($db->error);
  // }
  if ($db->connect_errno){
    throw new RuntimeException('mysqli connection error: ' . $db->connect_error);
  }
  return $db;
}

function h($value){
  return htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES);
}
session_start();
$db = dbconnect();

if ( isset( $_SESSION['id']) && $_SESSION['name']){
  $id = $_SESSION['id'];
  $name = $_SESSION['name'];
  $image = $_SESSION['image'];
}else{
  header('Location: login_admin.php');
  exit();
}

$hotel_id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

$error = [];

if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

  $title = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'title', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  if ( $title == ''){
    $error['title'] = 'blank';
  }

  $place = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'place', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  if ( $place == ''){
    $error['place'] = 'blank';
  }

  $introduction = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'introduction', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  if ( $introduction == ''){
    $error['introduction'] = 'blank';
  }


  if (empty($error)){
    $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE hotels SET title=?, place=?, introduction=? WHERE id=? ');
    if (! $stmt){
      die($db->error);
    }
    $stmt->bind_param('sssi', $title, $place, $introduction, $hotel_id);
    $success = $stmt->execute();
    if (! $success){
      die($db->error);
    }
    header('Location: view_admin.php?id=' . $hotel_id);
    exit();
  }


}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="../style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/08e90ee946.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php include 'header_admin.php' ?>

<div class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <h3 class="heading">宿泊施設の情報を変更する</h3>
    <?php
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT h.title, h.place, h.introduction FROM hotels h WHERE h.id=? LIMIT 1');
    if (! $stmt){
      die($db->error);
    }
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $hotel_id);
    $success = $stmt->execute();
    if (! $success){
      die($db->error);
    }
    $stmt->bind_result($title, $place, $introduction);
    if ( $stmt->fetch()) :
    ?>
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">タイトル</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" name="title" value="<?php echo h($title) ?>" placeholder="">
      <?php if ( isset($error['title']) && $error['title'] == 'blank') :?>
      <p class="error">タイトルを入力してください</p>
      <?php endif ?>
    </div> 
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">エリア</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" name="place" value="<?php echo h($place) ?>" placeholder="">
      <?php if ( isset($error['place']) && $error['place'] == 'blank') :?>
      <p class="error">エリアを入力してください</p>
      <?php endif ?>
    </div>     
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label">紹介文</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" name="introduction" rows="3"><?php echo h($introduction) ?></textarea>
      <?php if ( isset($error['introduction']) && $error['introduction'] == 'blank') :?>
      <p class="error">紹介文を入力してください</p>
      <?php endif ?>
    </div> 
    <?php endif ?>
    <div class="amenities-area">
      <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label">アメニティ</label>
      <div class="amenities">    
        <?php
        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT name FROM amenities');
        if (! $stmt){
          die($db->error);
        }
        $success = $stmt->execute();
        if (! $success){
          die($db->error);
        }
        $stmt->bind_result($a_name);
        while ( $stmt->fetch()) :
        ?>
        <div class="amenity">
          <input type="checkbox" class="" id="cb1" name="cb1">
          <label class="cb1" for="cb1"><?php echo h($a_name) ?></label>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">変更</button>
    </form>
    
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, there are 3 SQL sentence in the code.
I have no idea that the problem is in the SQL, HTML sentence or Datebase(phpMyAdmin).

Comment: Please try and minimize your code to show the problem, currently there is too much code to really see what is happening.  Also you say it isn't working - do you get any errors as they usually contain information which helps resolve the problem.

Comment: You should probably consider using this instead https://www.php.net/mysqli-stmt.get-result

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the same name for multiple queries.

Every name should be unique for multiple queries on the same page.

For example: `$stmt` for the first as it is, and for the second try a new name Like `$stmt1` or `$stmt_second`, then it works perfectly.

For first query leave it as it is:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT h.title, h.place, h.introduction FROM hotels h WHERE h.id=? LIMIT 1');
```

And for the second query change it to:

```
$stmt_second = $db->prepare('SELECT name FROM amenities');
```